# Unique Values from Multiple Fields using Arcpy and Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am using Python 2.7 and am trying to generate a list of unique values from all values within two fields (cropsum and cropsum2). I am not trying to find unique row combinations. I've tried using both methods from http://geospatialtraining.com/get-a-list-of-unique-attribute-values-using-arcpy/ but neither method is working for me using two fields. My preference is to use numpy as and I am trying to write a script to manipulate data from a Frequency tool dbf output.

Method 1: Search Cursor

```
in_table = 'frequencySoutheastSubset.dbf'
field_names = ['cropsum', 'cropsum2']
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(in_table, [field_names]) as cursor:
    uniqueCropCodes = sorted({row[0] for row in cursor})                   
    print uniqueCropCodes
```

returns the following error: 
TypeError: 'field_names' must be string or non empty sequence of strings

Method 2: Numpy

```
arr = arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray('frequencyNorthSubset.dbf',['cropsum', 'cropsum2'])
print(arr)

uniqueCropCodes = numpy.unique(arr)
print uniqueCropCodes
```

Returns unique row combinations, which is not what I want. 
The [numpy.unique](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) documentation example

```
>>> a = np.array([[1, 1], [2, 3]])
>>> np.unique(a)
array([1, 2, 3])
```

suggests that the code above should work.

I tried suggestions from this `np.unique(arr[['cropsum', 'cropsum2']].values)`
did not work either: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'values'

My dbf in case it's helpful:[image]

Comment: Remove the brackets around field_names in the cursor

Comment: @BERA Thanks, I just tried that and it only gives a list from the first column, cropsum [0, 1, 14, 31, 81, 98, 9811, 9817]. It doesn't add unique value 51 from cropsum2...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets):

> A set is an unordered collection with no duplicate elements

```
import arcpy
in_table = 'frequencySoutheastSubset.dbf'
field_names = ['cropsum', 'cropsum2']

all_values = []

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(in_table,field_names) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        all_values.extend(list(row))

unique_values = set(all_values)

print unique_values
```

This should also work:

```
from itertools import chain

unique_values = set(list(chain(*[i for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(in_table, field_names)]))
```